# sbt compile yields "object casbah is not a member of package com.mongodb"

Tags: mongodb, scala, sbt

My directory structure:

```
-build.sbt
-src
--main
---scala
----MongoConnect.scala
-lib
```

My `build.sbt`:

```
name := "mongodb-experiments"

version := "0.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.mongodb.casbah" %% "casbah" % "3.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

My MongoConnect.scala program:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
object MongoConnect{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    println("Hello Mongo")
  }
}
```

Why does `sbt compile` result in

> object casbah is not a member of package com.mongodb

?

```
sbt compile
[info] Set current project to mongodb-experiments (in build file:/Users/hrishikeshparanjape/git-public/mongodb-experiments/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/hrishikeshparanjape/git-public/mongodb-experiments/}default-fc358e...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.1 ...
[info] Resolving com.mongodb.casbah#casbah_2.9.1;3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[info] Resolving com.mongodb.casbah#casbah-util_2.9.1;3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.mongodb#mongo-java-driver;2.7.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scalaj#scalaj-collection_2.9.1;1.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.time#time_2.8.0;0.2 ...
[info] Resolving joda-time#joda-time;1.6 ...
[info] Resolving com.mongodb.casbah#casbah-commons_2.9.1;3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[info] Resolving com.mongodb.casbah#casbah-core_2.9.1;3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[info] Resolving com.mongodb.casbah#casbah-query_2.9.1;3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[info] Resolving com.mongodb.casbah#casbah-gridfs_2.9.1;3.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/hrishikeshparanjape/git-public/mongodb-experiments/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[error] /Users/hrishikeshparanjape/git-public/mongodb-experiments/src/main/scala/MongoConnect.scala:1: object casbah is not a member of package com.mongodb
[error] import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] {file:/Users/hrishikeshparanjape/git-public/mongodb-experiments/}default-fc358e/compile:compile: Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 7 s, completed Jul 26, 2012 11:53:35 PM
```

Comment: Interesting. If you go back to ``"org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.3.0-RC1"`` it works.

Comment: Even stranger, looking into my local Ivy cache, I find the file ``org.mongodb\cashbah-core_2.9.1\jars\casbah-core_2.9.1-2.3.0-RC1.jar``, but for ``3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`` I only find ``com.mongodb.casbah\casbah-core_2.9.1\jars\casbah-core_2.9.1-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar``. That looks as if only the sources have been downloaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14499/discussion-between-mhs-and-hrishikeshp19)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify your build.sbt file as:

```
name := "mongodb-experiments"

version := "0.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.mongodb.casbah" % "casbah_2.9.0" % "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

**For some reason, 3.0.0 does not work.**

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use snapshot repository with and old versions of casbah?

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.4.1"
)

resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
```

%% sign in dependency will choose configured in sbt scala version

For 3.x version there is a milestone

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "3.0.0-M2"
    )
```

And as I remember in 3.x import should be changed to:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah._
```

Comment: Works for me. But why the discrepancy between the Ivy dependency ``"org.mongodb"`` and the import from ``com.mongodb``?

Comment: Don't know. Seems import structures goes from previous versions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, typesafe seems to be bigger than sonatype.